# Cannot change app theme to Holo Dark

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm currently using Holo light with dark action bar and I want to change my app to completely use Holo. I changed styles.xml from

`"<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">"` to

```
"<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo ">"
```

and I changed styles.xml within values-14 from

`"<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">"` to

```
"<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.">"
```

yet nothing changes. I set my minSDK to 14 and my target to 19. Anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: Probably a dumb question, but do you have `android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme"` set in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file?

Answer (score 1):

I would check the AndroidManifest.xml file. There should be a node called: android:theme. Change it to android:theme="Theme.Holo.Light" >

Comment: I don't want it to be light though. I want it dark.

Comment: Then just use Theme.Holo.Dark instead

Comment: please consider accepting this answer if it has helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

See `AndroidManifest.xml` probably there is some lines like this:

```xml
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >  <!-- this line -->
```

this lines set a dynamic theme for your application that depend on SDK-level. you can set  values for each SDK by adding `values-vxx/styles.xml` like `values-v10/styles.xml` for SDK-10.

but your minimum SDK is 14 that support Holo and Holo.Light themes so you can change theme directly in manifest.

So write in AdnroidManifest.xml like this:

```xml
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo" >
```

write `"@android:style/Theme.Holo"` because you're using android resources.